# Copying a range of files with a windows batch script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy a range of files "Client_5001.txt" to "Client_5814.txt" to another folder with a batch script, but I cannot seem to get the correct syntax. So far I have unsuncessfully tried the follwoing code:

```
for %%I in (X:\Client_500{1..814}.txt) do copy %%I %cd%\client_files\
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even if `{1..814}` meant something in a batch file, which it doesn't, `Client_500814.txt` wouldn't match `Client_5814.txt` anyhow. Perhaps you are looking for [tag:powershell] solutions, not [tag:cmd] ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a loop numeric to do this:

```
For /L %%i in (5001 1 5814)do if /I exist x:\client_%%i.txt copy x:\Client_%%i.txt .\client_files\
```

Your regex are not working, possible working in vbs, but not in cmd/bat